# How to create DLL file of DTD files?

Tags: dll, dtd

I have 9 DTD files example
[xhtml dtd1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11-flat.dtd)
[xhtml dtd2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd)

I want to create a DLL file which includes all the 9 dtd's.
So any of you can help me in creating it or tell me from where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you publish your web app or compile your site it will transform these into a dll if they reside in a class library.

Comment: It is not doing so.
i have put all the DTD files in the folder in my local system.then its working fine.if i load in repository den its not working for me.so i want to create the DLL of these DTD's .Can u tell me how to do that? Thanks...

Comment: Are you doing a web application, web site or windows application

Comment: If you are doing a web site it compiles this behind the scenes into your aspnet temporary folder (so you won't be able to use the dll).  If you refactor it out to a class library then you should be able to compile it into a dll and then reference that.